# Android Studio 3.1.4 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01' error

Tags: android

is there any fix to this error? 
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'

Error Log:

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 28.0.0-rc01, 26.1.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0-rc01 and com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0 less... (Ctrl+F1) 
>   There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your targetSdkVersion).

what does it need me to do?

Here is my gradle file:

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
```

Comment: Post gradle file of your app

Comment: Possible Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374151/all-com-android-support-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version-specification

Comment: @kevanaghera i dont understand what it needs me to add to the gradle file

Comment: Go your project structure and check all module dependency. Try to set all support dependency use same version. Hope you got the issue.

Comment: still notifies there is an error but it still works

Comment: what is your compileSdkVersion and targetedSdkVersion?

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the instructions and the error will be gone. Add the following dependencies to the gradle file because you must have to use the same version of library in your project for smooth operation of app.

> implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0-rc01'
>     implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0-rc01'

Actually android studio provides all the information (errors and warning) to ease the development.

And also a suggestion change the **compile** to **implementation** in the firebase-core library